# mapnik error - fatal flex scanner internal error--end of buffer missed

Tags: python, tiles, spatialite, mapnik, geodjango

I am using Mapnik 2.0.1rc0 on a Windows 7 with python 2.7 32bits inside a GeoDjango App. I often got this error: `fatal flex scanner internal error--end of buffer missed` that makes python to crash (sometimes python crash without error message) when zooming in and out of mapnik tiles rendered in OpenLayers map. The tiled data are stored in spatialite 4.0.

I know such setup could provide a lot of source for this crash. Anybody has encountered this error before or may know where to look to make it works without crashing?

**Edit:**

GeoDjango is used as a Tile Map Server. I start by creating the xml in python then I use mapnik python bindings to generate the tiles. The data is already stored in spatialite. So each time I zoom in and out in the map, mapnik query spatialite like this:

```
    query = '(select ' + geometryField + ', "id" from "shapefile_feature" where' + ' shapefile_id=' + str(shapefile.id) + ') as geom'
    datasource = mapnik.SQLite(file='C:\mygeosite\sqlite3\sql3.db',
                                    table=query,
                                    srid=4326,
                                    geometry_field=geometryField)
```

Comment: That message is coming from libspatialite (one of the parsers - WKT, JSON, GML, KML, etc). It isn't clear to me how this could happen without understanding what you're doing in GeoDjango.

Comment: The question was edited... I hope its clear enought

Comment: Its difficult to know, but I'm guessing you've got a bad build - perhaps the versions of spatialite / sqlite don't match with what django is providing. Do you have more than one sqlite3.dll on your system?